# padding ALL variables in a dataframe by group

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), 
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), 
                             np.nan, 
                             pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')],
                   'group' : ['a',np.nan,'b','b'],
                   'value' : [1,2,3,np.nan],
                   'value_useless' : [2,2,np.nan,2]})

df
Out[101]: 
        date group   value  value_useless
0 2018-01-01     a 1.00000        2.00000
1 2018-01-01   NaN 2.00000        2.00000
2        NaT     b 3.00000            nan
3 2018-01-01     b     nan        2.00000
```

Here I want to forward fill all the variables in the dataframe - by group.

According to the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html) I should be able to do this:

```
df.groupby('group').fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
Out[110]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

crazy stuff.
What is the issue here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.groupby('group')` is producing a `groupby` object thing that hasn't been assigned to a name.  You are then doing a `fillna` with an `inplace=True`.  When you use `inplace=True` you alter the calling dataframe and return a bunch of nothing.  **And** you toss that calling dataframe into the void.

```
df.groupby('group').ffill()
```

Should do you just fine.

---

Another way to look at it:

```
# Copy                       Altered Copy In-Place... returning None
# |                          |
# v                          v
df.copy().set_index('group', inplace=True)
```

Where did the copy go?  That object is now sitting in memory waiting for the garbage collector.

Comment: I see, thanks. the puzzling thing is that `df.groupby('group').fillna(method = 'ffill')` loses the `group` variable while `df.groupby('group').ffill()` does not.

Comment: That is a bit goofy.